# get_option returning old value for non-admin users

Tags: plugins, options

I am working on multisite with sub-folders.
I am trying to create a plugin that will simply reduce the click counts and those counts will be visible to all users. 
For admin user all is working fine. But, for un-signedin user, I am getting some old value of option.

Following is the code;

```
add_action('wp_footer','click_counter');

function click_counter() {
?>
    <div class="cc-container">
        <span class="cc-counter"><?php echo get_option('click_counter_max'); ?></span>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

=================[EDIT]===============

Complete plugin script

```
function cc_clicked_callback() {
    $value = get_option('click_counter_max');
    $newValue = $value - 1;
    update_option('click_counter_max', $newValue);
    wp_die();
}

function click_counter_install() {
    /* Creates new database field */
    add_option("click_counter_max", '100', '', no);
}

function click_counter_remove() {
    delete_option('click_counter_max');
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cc_clicked', 'cc_clicked_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_cc_clicked', 'cc_clicked_callback');
add_action('wp_footer','click_counter');

function click_counter() {
    wp_enqueue_script('cc-ajax-user-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/user-ajax.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
    wp_localize_script('cc-ajax-user-script', 'ccOptionDetails', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
    wp_enqueue_style('cc-user-style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'css/click-counter.css');
?>
    <div class="cc-container">
        <span class="cc-counter"><?php echo get_option('click_counter_max'); ?></span>
    </div>
<?php
}
if ( is_admin() ){
    /* Runs when plugin is activated */
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'click_counter_install'); 

    /* Runs on plugin deactivation*/
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'click_counter_remove' );


/* Call the html code */
    add_action('admin_menu', 'click_counter_admin_menu');

    function click_counter_admin_menu() {
        add_options_page('Click Counter', 'Click Counter', 'administrator',
            'click-counter', 'click_counter_html_page');
    }

    function click_counter_html_page() {
?>
        <div>
            <h2>Click Counter Options</h2>

            <form id="click-counter-setting-form" method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>

                <table width="510">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th width="92" scope="row">Enter Max Counter Number</th>
                        <td width="406">
                            <input name="click_counter_max" type="text" id="click_counter_max"
                                value="<?php echo get_option('click_counter_max'); ?>" />
                        (ex. 100)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
                <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="click_counter_max" />
                <p>
                    <?php submit_button(); ?>
                </p>

            </form>
            <p id="click_counter_msgs">
            </p>
        </div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with this... the error is maybe somewhere else...

Comment: @Reigel please check updated question.